# Don't know what is wrong with my gaussian filter

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a program to detect borders of an image and the first step I'm taking is applying a gaussian filter to remove noise. The problem is that the filter that I'm applying only makes the image darker and doesn't blur it as it is supposed to.

This is the code that I haVe at the moment:

```
void gaussFilter(C_Image &imagen, float desviation) {
    float kernel[5][5];
    float sumaKernel = 0;
    float s = desviation * desviation;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            float xaxis = (1 / sqrt(2 * M_PI * s)) * pow(exp(-pow(i, 2)) / (2 * s), 1);
            float yaxis = (1 / sqrt(2 * M_PI * s)) * pow(exp(-pow(j, 2)) / (2 * s), 1);
            float gaussianFilter = xaxis * yaxis;
            kernel[i][j] = gaussianFilter; 
            sumaKernel += kernel[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "Suma kernel: " << sumaKernel << endl;

    //Normaizamos el kernel;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            kernel[i][j] /= sumaKernel;
        }
    }

    C_Image::IndexT rowN, colN, colorsN;
    C_Image::BMPFileInfo("barbara_gray.bmp", rowN, colN, colorsN);

    //filterCreation(kernel, 10);
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            if (y != 4) {
                printf("%f|", kernel[x][y]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%f|\n", kernel[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Numero de columnas: " << colN << "\nNumero de filas: " << rowN << "\nColores de la paleta: " << colorsN << endl;
    float suma;

    for (int x = 1; x <= imagen.LastRow(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= imagen.LastCol(); y++)
        { 
            suma = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    suma += imagen(x, y) * kernel[i][j];

                }
            }
                    imagen(x, y) = suma;

        }
    }
}
```

And this is my main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char const* path = "barbara_gray.bmp";

    C_Image imagen;
    imagen.ReadBMP(path);
    gaussFilter(imagen, 10);
    char const* destinationPath = "result_image.bmp";
    imagen.WriteBMP(destinationPath);
}
```

C_Image is a class given.

Comment: You're not using the kernel correctly.

Comment: how should i use the kernel?

Comment: Recheck your algorithm for the Guassian filter.  Fundamentally, since the filter should be blurring the picture, it should be blending multiple pixel values together to get the blurred pixel.  Your current code does not do that.

Comment: Yes, but i don´t know if what is wrong is the part where i calculate the gaussian filter and i add it to sumaKernel variable or if i´m wrong in the part where i multiply each pixel of the image by each position of the kernel

Comment: Shouldn't it be `kernel[i][j] = std::exp(-(i * i + j * j) / (2 * s)) / (2 * M_PI * s);`?